# Get values from Database as key pair

Tags: java, jpa

I have this table which I would like to store different values as keys and vales:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wpf_payment_attributes")
public class WpfPaymentAttributes implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2629784870868584850L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String global_ley;

    @Column(name = "VALUE", columnDefinition = "TEXT", length = 65535)
    private String value;
    ....
}

WpfPaymentAttributes attibutes = new WpfPaymentAttributes();
attibutes.setName("usage");
attibutes.setValue("Test Usage");
attibutes.setGlobal_key(12333);

WpfPaymentAttributes attibutes = new WpfPaymentAttributes();
attibutes.setName("name");
attibutes.setValue("Peter");
attibutes.setGlobal_key(12333);
```

But how I can get all value with the same global key with one SQL query using JPA? The problem is that I don't know in advance what are the table columns and values.

I need to get this structure:

```
usage      | name
-------------------
Test Usage | Peter
```

Is this possible with JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, since there are some issues that JPA won't be able to help you with:

- there could be multiple `WpfPaymentAttributes` values with the same
  global key and name (however, this could be solved by using a
  database constraint);
- there could be arbitrary values in the `name`
  column, hence you'd have to make sure that they actually map to your expected result structure, there are no unknown "names" etc.

If you don't need a super-generic system, I'd advice you to write a simple mapper, that shouldn't be very complex. Just get all `WpfPaymentAttributes` by a specific `global_key` and apply the mapping. For example, here's the structure that you need:

```java
public class Result {
    private String usage;
    private String name;
    // ...
}
```

And then:

```java
Result result = new Result();
List<WpfPaymentAttributes> attributes = entityManager.createQuery(
    // query should be parameterized
    "select a from WpfPaymentAttributes a where global_key = 12333" 
).getResultList();
for (WpfPaymentAttributes attribute : attributes) {
    String value = attribute.getValue();
    switch(attribute.getName()) {
        case "name":
            result.setName(value);
            break;
        case "usage":
            result.setUsage(value);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
} 
return result;
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. I will try it.